# Java: Select class member by string

Tags: java

Is there a way in Java to get a member of a class using the name of said member.

Say we have a class as such:

```
public class intClass {
    public int x;
    public intClass(x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to do something similar to:

```
intClass newIntClass = new intClass(4);
String memberName = "x";
int y = newIntClass.[memberName];
```

Comment: **Warning**: Reflection is powerful; use wisely.